# string mutation

Tags: string, uppercase, lowercase, mutation

I am trying to create a string mutation that, after a prompt for a city and state, would output the state in uppercase, followed directly by the city in lowercase, followed directly by the state again in uppercase.
I have tried many types of mutations but nothing is working.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Does it not have ways to convert strings or individual characters between cases and concatenate them?

Answer (score 0):

use [`String#toUpperCase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) and [`String#toLowerCase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) methods.

eg. `System.out.println(state.toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in **java**

```
Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
String city,state;
System.out.println("Enter City =");
city=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter State =");
state=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println( state.toUpperCase() + " "+city.toLowerCase() + " "+ state.toUpperCase());
```

**Independent of any programming language(But dependent on character Representation)** you could retrieve every character of string and add 22 which would convert UPPERCASE into LOWERCASE.As you must be knowing **ASCII** values of **a-z is 97-122** and that of **A-Z is 65-90**.so you can lookout how much to add/ subtract to convert between cases.